# stop handler.postDelayed when moving to another tab in tabview

Tags: android, handler, tabview, postdelayed

in my apps, i'm using tabview. inside one of the tab i implement a refresh function such as:

```
private final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mVar = true;
        while (mVar == true){
            calculateResult();
            //refresh();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
};
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_view);
    refresh();
    setBackGround();
}
public void refresh() {
    new Thread(r).start();
    //handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

i already try using `handler.removeCallbacks(r);` in order to stop the handler to repeat it self or so what i believe. but the system just crash when i start it.

> here is my error log:

```
04-23 01:14:20.234: D/dalvikvm(14753): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 53K, 47% free 2868K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 37ms
04-23 01:14:20.265: D/ATRecorder(14753): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@405178e8
04-23 01:14:20.275: D/WindowManagerImpl(14753): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40523840
04-23 01:14:23.368: D/dalvikvm(14753): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 17K, 47% free 2901K/5379K, external 1151K/1663K, paused 23ms
04-23 01:14:23.518: D/dalvikvm(14753): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 86K, 45% free 2960K/5379K, external 2320K/2875K, paused 24ms
04-23 01:14:23.678: D/dalvikvm(14753): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3K, 45% free 2961K/5379K, external 8073K/10082K, paused 25ms
04-23 01:14:23.798: D/ATRecorder(14753): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@4053b728
04-23 01:14:23.878: D/dalvikvm(14753): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 45% free 2969K/5379K, external 13845K/15875K, paused 28ms
04-23 01:14:23.898: D/ATRecorder(14753): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@40531240
04-23 01:14:23.908: D/WindowManagerImpl(14753): addView, new view, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40512848
04-23 01:14:24.108: W/dalvikvm(14753): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3165)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:677)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8507)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:330)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageView.java:344)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at com.FYP.indoorGPS.TouchImageView.setImageBitmap(TouchImageView.java:153)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at com.FYP.indoorGPS.MapActivity.drawMap(MapActivity.java:163)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at com.FYP.indoorGPS.MapActivity$1.run(MapActivity.java:31)
04-23 01:14:24.108: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
04-23 01:14:24.379: D/WindowManagerImpl(14753): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40523840
04-23 01:14:24.419: D/WindowManagerImpl(14753): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40512848
04-23 01:14:26.030: D/Process(14753): killProcess, pid=14753
```

can anyone tell me what should i do?

Comment: i've add it. please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is that your Runnable "r" is still running even after `removeCallbacks()`.  `removeCallbacks()` doesn't stop a running Runnable, it just keeps it from getting started.

Also, your `refresh()` calls "r" again, so it will be called indefinitely.  So, if `removeCallbacks()` is called while "r" is running, you have no code to stop "r" and it will loop forever.

A solution would to have a loop in your Runnable and call `Thread.sleep()` at the end of each loop.  Then simply end the loop to stop the Runnable.

For example, in your Runnable:

```
public void run() {
    mVar = true;
    while (mVar == true){
        //do stuff
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

}
```

Let mVar be a static variable that you can set to false to end the loop.

Also, I would suggest not running this Runnable on the UI thread, as it will likely cause your app to stop responding during the `Thread.sleep(2000)` method.  You could use the following:

```
new Thread(r).start();
```

EDIT: If you are going to be handling Views in your Runnable, then the code that handles the views **must** be run from the UI thread.  So, any code altering your views from a runnable needs to be called via a handler.

Comment: so, any idea what should i do to stop runnable running?

Comment: i'm sorry, but i didn't understand where else should i put the runnable then? is it in another class and then i create the object of that class inside the UI? then how to use the new Thread(r).start()? i'm quiet new in android. sorry.

Comment: Basically, using the above you would have to remove the Handler and use new Thread(r).start() to start "r" rather than using handler.post(r).  Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, it does. thanks. but now my system crash the moment it start. is it caused by run new Thread(r).start()? did i need to add anything in front? i try using 'Thread t = new Thread(r); t.start()' but it still crash. and i haven't set anything to make mvar = false cause i want try to run it first.

Comment: i have edit the question and post new error. please have a look at it because actually i don't understand this error also. sorry

Comment: Edited... again.  You can't access Views from any thread except the UI thread.

Comment: sorry, i don't get what you mean by UI thread. And you say i need to use a handler. so i need to change my code back using handler.postDelayed(r,2000)? it's already late here. i might only try this again tomorrow. thank alot for helping me.

Comment: The UI thread is the main Thread.  Unless you specify otherwise, almost everything you write will be on the UI thread.  A handler is often used to access the UI thread from another thread.  For example, you can define a handler at the top of your class.  Then, you initialize it during the OnCreate() method.  Then, from another thread, you call mHandler.post(r) to post the Runnable "r".  This means that r will actually be run on the main "UI" thread.  So, you can do background tasks on a thread, then alter the UI using mHandle.post().  Trying to change your views from a thread will crash.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. But aren't what you say now contradict with what you say previously about i should not use the runnable in the UI class since it cause my app to stop during thread.sleep(2000)? Did it means that you solution was not suitable for my problem because i'm changing view inside my runnable? sorry if i get it wrong.

Comment: Send me an email at root.lrandroid@gmail.com and hopefully I can explain this and we can get it working.

Comment: i've send you an email and the code. please have a look at it. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Handler is better solution rather then Thread.
See below code, it should work. I assume that mVar is a controlled variable, that is going to be set as false to stop handler.

```
private final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (mVar) {
            calculateResult();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_view);
    refresh();
    setBackGround();
}

public void refresh() {
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```